# How to always jump ssh/scp to a new host?

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn

I have an external VPS that has a VPN connection to another server using `tinc` on the ip address `10.0.0.2`.

I am wanting to connect to my other server via ssh and scp over one command when connecting over a specific user - `foo`.

I am able to do this over `ssh` by adding this to my VPS `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match User foo
    ForceCommand ssh -t root@10.0.0.2 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

Unfortunately when attempting `scp` (`scp ~/Desktop/hello.txt foo@vps_ip:/`) with this config I get:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: Permanently added '10.0.0.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-70-generic x86_64)
mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Also the same

Answer (score 0):

Your ForceCommand needs to run a script that dynamically determines the correct ssh command.

- Add `"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"` as the remote command if the variable is non-empty locally. This allows things like `ssh firsthost "uname -a"` (for example) to correctly pass through to the second host.
- Add `-t` **only if** stdin/stdout are a terminal. Batch transfers (scp, sftp, rsync, git) require a 8-bit-clean stream and forcing tty allocation would corrupt the data.
- Consider not stacking SSH this way in the first place – better use either port-forwarding (iptables DNAT) or client-side JumpCommand.